# Deduction fails in VisualStudio 2013 with first template argument being a specific type (which in turn is arbitrarily templated)

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I want to have a certain function that does a computation if the Argument is a certain  template with a specific first template parameter (arbitrarily templated).

Consider these classes

```
template<class S> struct A { };
template<class S> struct B { };
template<class S> struct C { };
template<class S, class U = B<S>> struct D { };
```

I tried to achieve my goal using

```
template<template<class ... X> class Y, class Z>
inline void foo(Y<A<Z>> const &av) { std::cout << "2\n"; }
```

#### Problem: MSVS 2013 is not able to deduce `Y`.

```
int main()
{
  foo(C<A<int>>()); // prints 2 as intended
  foo(D<A<int>>()); // does NOT compile in VS 2013
  return 0;
}
```

The reason for the error (according to MSVS) is:

> template-Argument for `const Y<A<Z>> &` cannot be deduced from `D<A<int>, B<S>>` with `S=A<int>`.

**My goal is to write an overload / specialization that handles any given type `Y` where `Y::value_type` / the first template parameter of `Y` can be any `A<T>` where the signature of foo is to be preserved: `void foo (Y const &);`**

Is this a Bug in MSVS (since `foo(D<A<int>>());` does in fact print 2 using g++) or am I missing something?

*PS: Merry Christmas if you care...*

Comment: `,class Z, class...Zs>` then `Y<A<Z>,Zs...>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`D<A<int>, B<S>>` is not `Y<A<Z>>`, you have to add the extra parameter:

```
template<template<class...> class Y, class Z, typename ... Ts>
inline void foo(Y<A<Z>, Ts...> const &av) { std::cout << "2\n"; }
```

Where `Ts...` can be empty.

An alternative is to make a alias:

```
template <typename T>
using E = D<A<T>>;
```

and then

```
foo(E<A<int>>()); // OK, but still can't use foo(D<A<int>>());
```

Comment: The moment when you're told: "You were hit by the truck of obviousness"... :) Thanks a lot. (Eventhough, I'm still puzzled by the different behavior of gcc and VS.)